# how can I auto-authenticate to a specific google account using java code?(auto-authenticate)

Tags: java, android, api, google-drive-api, credentials

I am trying to create an application that uses google drive as storage, this application is somehow private. however, I don't want it to ask me to log in not even once, I don't mind the application knowing the full credentials it needs to access the google drive it will use.
In short, is there a way to auto-authenticate my app to fully access a certain google drive by saving the google account somewhere?

Comment: For connecting to the drive, you will need to access the drive APIs. The APIs will need credentials. In your application, whenever you need to do some synch up, you will invoke APIs. What you can do is to store the APIs in some file locally (preferably encrypted) and whenever, invoking the APIs, read those credentials and pass to the APIs.

Comment: could you please provide me with the java code? I've been trying to search for a way to invoke the API using credentials but I couldn't find it. So If you know the code please supply it, thanks a lot

Comment: Please refer https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/examples